# restore of webview state not working in android

Tags: android

I have two layout files for potrait and landscape like layout and layout-land. I have a webview in my layout. I want to restore the state of webview. Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Can anybody tell me how to retrieve the state of the url?

In manifest file I didn't mention `android:confichanges="orientation"` because of two design
I have done like this below but its not working. Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

Save the state:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
{     
      commentWebView.saveState(outState); 

      // (WebView) findViewById(R.id.txtComment).saveState(outState);
}
```

and restore the state:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null) 
 {
      //((WebView)findViewById(R.id.txtComment)).restoreState(savedInstanceState); } 
      commentWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState); 
      if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                {
                  imgInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info);
                imgComment.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.commentsactive);
                commentWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

         } 
          else
          {

     String url="http://preview.unstructure.org/unstruc/unstruc.php?i="+videoPostBean.getVideo_title().replaceAll(" ", "-");

     commentWebView.loadUrl(url);
          }
```

Thanks